# JavaScript bug, battleships game

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started learning JS and I made a very simple game. It's a simple battleships game with no animations. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Game.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

    <marquee id="output"></marquee>

    <script>
        var loc1,loc2,loc3;
        var guess;
        var hits = 0;
        var guesses = 0;
        var isSunk = false;
        var locRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

        loc1 = locRandom;
        loc2 = loc1 + 1;
        loc3 = loc2 + 1;



    while(isSunk == false){

            guess = prompt("Enter a number from 1-10");

        if(guess == null){
                alert("Bye");
            promt.close;
        }

       else if(guess < 0 || guess > 10 || guess == "" || guess == " "){


                alert("Write a valid number");
            }
            else
            {
            guesses = guesses + 1;  

            if(guess == loc1 || guess == loc2 || guess == loc3) {
                alert("HIT!");    
                hits = hits + 1;

                    if(hits == 3){
                        isSunk = true;
                        alert("You sank my battleship!");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("MISS");
                }
            }

        }
    var stats = "You took " + guesses  + " guesses to sink the battleship, " + "which means that  your accuracy is " + (3/guesses) + " hit(s) per guess";
        alert(stats);
        alert("Thanks for playing!");
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Refresh to play again!";
        document.write("<br><br>This game was created by Swegre Designs");
    </script>





</body>
```

But the thing is, when I for example get a "HIT" on the number 1, then I could type 1 three times in the promt and the battleship is sunk, but that's not what should be happening, I hope you understand the bug, can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not keeping track of any previous guesses by your user.

You can keep track of the guessed locations by using an array.  For example:

```
var guessedPositions = [];
```

Then when you receive input from the user, push their guessed location into the array:

```
guessedPositions.push(guess);
```

You will then have to compare the `guessedPositions` with the users `guess`, you could make a function for this:

```
function alreadyGuessed(userGuess) {
   for(var i=0; i<guessedPositions.length;i++) {
      if (guessedPositions[i] == userGuess) {
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

You can invoke this by:  `alreadyGuessed(guess);`

Which will return true or false if that entry is in the array.

**Edit - from your comment**

```
while(isSunk == false){

 guess = prompt("Enter a number from 1-10");

  if (guess == null){
     alert("Bye");
     promt.close;
  }

  else if(guess < 0 || guess > 10 || guess == "" || guess == " "){
      alert("Write a valid number");
  }
  else if (alreadyGuessed(guess)) { // This is the line you are looking for.
     alert("You have already guessed " + guess + ", please enter a different location");
  }
  else
  {
```

Comment: Hi Darren, I tried it, but didn't get it to work, if you have time, could you write your function directly in my code so I could see exactly how you mean?

Comment: @SwegreDesigns - I've added it in my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a bug - here's what's happening

```
 if(guess == loc1 || guess == loc2 || guess == loc3)
```

isn't taking into account whether they have already guessed the location or not. I'd keep track of which positions they have already guessed in an array, then use that to check if it is a new guess or not. Or, you could put all of the "hittable" locations in an array, then when they guess a correct one, remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember which of the three locations they hit, and don't let them try to hit that location a subsequent time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't hit location 0? If so, you can just set the desired loc var to 0 whenever it is hit.

Comment: 0 is indeed a valid location in the user's code. -1 would work, though.